# How to use GitHub commit message and commit id inside Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: git, jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline

I am using DevOps model, where i have built a pipeline for code build and deploy.
In the entire process i want to log the Git commit id and commit message for that specific change commits.

```
@shruthibhaskar
shruthibhaskar committed just now 
1 parent 51132c4 commit aedd3dc56ab253419194762d72f2376aede66a19
```

and commit message and description as below

```
test commit 3

test commit desc 3
```

how do i access these values of commit inside my jenkins pipeline, where i have configured a webhook for SCM polling?

Answer (score 6):

`git log --format=format:%s -1` (latest commit)

`git log --format=format:%s -1 ${GIT_COMMIT}` (specific commit)

`git --no-pager show -s --format='%s' ${GIT_COMMIT}`

Answer (score 5):

Jenkins git plugin set some environment variables for every build. You can find the list of them in [git plugin site](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin). In which it gives the SHA of the current commit in ***${GIT_COMMIT}*** environment variable.

You can use the SHA along with git log to print commit message and any other details you required with --pretty option.

```
git log --oneline -1 ${GIT_COMMIT} # prints SHA and title line
git log --format="medium" -1 ${GIT_COMMIT} # print commit, author, date, title & commit message
```

Comment: Thank you, i also figured GIT_COMMIT, but however i did not find any environment variable for commit message.

Comment: As explained already, you can print the git message with "Git log" command. if you are using pipeline then, you can go sh 'git log --oneline -1 ${GIT_COMMIT}'

Answer (score 3):

You can make a message based on `currentBuild.changeSets`, for example:

```
@NonCPS
def sendChangeLogs() {
    def commitMessages = ""
    def formatter = new SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm')
    def changeLogSets = currentBuild.changeSets
    for (int i = 0; i < changeLogSets.size(); i++) {
        def entries = changeLogSets[i].items
        for (int j = 0; j < entries.length; j++) {
            def entry = entries[j]
            commitMessages = commitMessages + "${entry.author} ${entry.commitId}:\n${formatter.format(new Date(entry.timestamp))}: *${entry.msg}*\n" 
        }
    }
    slackSend color: "good", message: "Job: `${env.JOB_NAME}`. Starting build with changes:\n${commitMessages}"
}
```

And call it:

```
stage('Clone repository') {
    steps {
        checkout scm

        script {
            sendChangeLogs()
        }
    }
}
```

P.S.

`@NonCPS` needs to except serialization error.
I've found it [here](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/217630098-How-to-access-Changelogs-in-a-Pipeline-Job-)

Comment: This works in most cases. If you have an empty commit with only a message then this will sadly not work because no changes were detected.

Answer (score 0):

you can  curl the api with personal token for gitlab scm to get the commit message & numerous other information. Here you need create personal token and  save it in jenkins via secret text & then use it in pipeline stages.

`curl --header "Private-Token: asdfasdfasdf"  https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/2445653/repository/commits/master`

you can check out the documentation for more information.
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOtIM.png)