# How to get the git latest commit message in jenkins and apply regular expressions on it to find needed data?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

i need to build a job in Jenkins, to get latest git commit message every time a commit is done and to store it in a variable.Can anyone suggest a plugin or a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use command line and get the commit message that you want and create a file as key value and inject the variable:

Step by step:

1. Install git plugin, EnvInject Plugin.
2. Get the last git commit by the command `git log -p -1` and parse from that what you need.
3. Create a file as key value for example `LAST_COMMIT_ID=cab123gfbdak`
4. Use the envInject as file (this load the key value file that you created to Jenkins as Jenkins variable).

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Need to analyze a `currentBuild.changeSets`. Full answer in another [stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56902550/2216279). Also, you can read a doc [here](https://opensource.triology.de/jenkins/pipeline-syntax/globals#currentBuild)