# How to run deploy stage only if commit message contains `[ci:deploy]`

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a pipeline in Jenkins and Github.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Verify Branch') {
            steps {
                echo "$GIT_BRANCH"
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo "build now"
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo "test now"
                // sh '''#!/bin/bash
                //  echo "hello world" 
                //  exit 1
                // '''
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                echo "deploy now"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to tell Jenkins to run the deploy stage only only if commit messge contains `[ci:deploy]`?

for example only if my commit is: `[ci:deploy] deploy the app` then run the deploy stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the Git commit message, you can use the example explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50856646/361089). Pasting here for reference:

```
git log --oneline -1 ${GIT_COMMIT} # prints SHA and title line
git log --format="medium" -1 ${GIT_COMMIT} # print commit, author, date, title & commit message
```

Along with this, you can make use of `when` expression that Jenkins provides. A snippet from the [official blog](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/01/19/converting-conditional-to-pipeline/#converting-to-pipeline)

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        git_commit_msg = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git log --format="medium" -1 ${GIT_COMMIT} | tail -1').trim()
    }

    stages {
        stage ('Check string') {
            when {
                // Use 'git_commit_msg' here to check the string you're interested in
                expression { env.git_commit_msg ==~ /[cd:deploy]/ }
            }
            steps {
                echo "Found string!"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Groovy regex: https://www.regular-expressions.info/groovy.html

Comment: The problem with this solution, I can't understand how to combine the two codes together. I read the docs, but where I put the `git log ..` ? I want Jenkins to read my commit message and then trigger the stage.

Comment: You can use the `git log` command in the `environment` block as shown in this example: `https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/01/19/converting-conditional-to-pipeline/#git_branch`. Then, you can use that variable inside a `stage` in `when` condition.