# How do you identify what repo a change set was generated by?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Using an example found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50856212/how-to-use-github-commit-message-and-commit-id-inside-jenkins-pipeline) I can access all the change sets for a build like this:

```
@NonCPS
def sendChangeLogs() {
    def commitMessages = ""
    def formatter = new SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm')
    def changeLogSets = currentBuild.changeSets
    for (int i = 0; i < changeLogSets.size(); i++) {
        def entries = changeLogSets[i].items
        for (int j = 0; j < entries.length; j++) {
            def entry = entries[j]
            commitMessages = commitMessages + "${entry.author} ${entry.commitId}:\n${formatter.format(new Date(entry.timestamp))}: *${entry.msg}*\n" 
        }
    }
}
```

The problem though is that I use shared libraries and the change set includes changes made to a shared library the pipeline is using.

I have not been able to figure out how to filter the change sets by repo to exclude shared library changes.

It's not enough to filter by just file path.

The change set class doesn't have a repo field or anything like that: https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/scm/ChangeLogSet.Entry.html

Comment: I believe this is a known issue of accessing those attributes when a shared library is imported into a pipeline.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I could retrieve the current commit id from the scm object after checkout and use that to filter the change sets, but I was really hoping to get all this git info _before_ checkout.